# what is the difference between: calculating MAPE using sklearn.metrics as metrics and using tensorflow.keras.losses

Tags: python, python-3.x

i applied both on time series data while making the prediction of stock price....

```
from tensorflow.keras.losses 
import mean_absolute_percentage_error as mape
```

`np.mean(mape(np.array(Y_test),pred))` and it shows `result 4.29` and then i applied

```
from sklearn.metrics 
import mean_absolute_percentage_error
```

`mean_absolute_percentage_error(Y_test, pred)` and it shows `result 0.44`

suggest the best one and what is the difference between them
thank you.

suggestion and best solutions